# Visual Studio 2008 - Status Bar Icon Glossary?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide

I have scoured the help files for Visual Studio and could not locate any information as to the meaning of some the icons in the status bar along the bottom of the main window of the IDE.

Does anyone know of a reference?

Specifically, there is an icon that shows a pair of binoculars over an animated page with boxes scrolling down it.

[alt text http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/358/vs2008statusbar.png](http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/358/vs2008statusbar.png)

Comment: What do you mean by status bar? Where it says "Ready..." "Compilation Started..." etc?

Comment: I think this question would make more sense to everybody if you provided a screen shot.

Comment: In Visual Studio, please go to; Tools >> Options >> Environment >> General - check "Show status bar". Does checking/unchecking and clicking "Ok" make the status bar appear/disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That'll be your "Find In Files" animation.

You can see it at the bottom of this image:

[alt text http://msmvps.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/peterritchie/lean-VS2k8.JPG](http://msmvps.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/peterritchie/lean-VS2k8.JPG)

The only other icons I've seen on there are Build and Save.

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense that with our large solution I may have had a search that was running in the background and forgotten about it!  :)

Comment: Then why does it appear whenever I have keyboard focus inside the text editor, and not when the focus is inside another window?

Answer (score 2):

On the bottom of this MSDN article you can find table with predefined VS status bar animations:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsstatusbar.animation.aspx

---

0 Standard animation icon

1 Animation when printing

2 Animation when saving files

3 Animation when deploying the solution

4 Animation when synchronizing files over the network

5 Animation when building the solution

6 Animation when searching

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only icons that appear there are when you are building a project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the "Error List"

Errors - A red circle with a white X
Warnings - Yellow triangle with black !
Info - White circle with blue i

Errors, stop you code being compiled.
Warnings, are possibe problems which can be ignored (but probably shouldn't)
Info, tells you information

Comment: No, I mean the status bar at the bottom of the main IDE window.